# how to create iPhone main menu screen with 2 tabbars subview?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I made two applications that each one of them is tabbar based.
Now I want to combine them to one app that will be struct like that:
-Main menu with 2 buttones.
  - button 1: tab bar app no 1.
  - button 2: tab bar app no 2.

from each tab bar app, I want an Home button on the left side of the nav bar that will take me to the main menu.

I found this link http://www.pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=27 but it's not good to me..
I will be happy if you will able to post some simple code for my problem..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App's 1 & 2 need to be based around viewcontrollers, each of which has a tabbar. The root windows can then just alloc/init and then `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];` to launch the tabbar controller.

If you have relied on IB to build your tabbar applications, its quite difficult to translate them into view controllers. I create my tabbars programatically (i just find it easier) like this

`tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];          // creates your tab bar so you can add everything else to it`

searchTableViewController = [[SearchTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *searchTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchTableViewController] autorelease];
[searchTableViewController release];

searchMapViewController = [[SearchMapViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *mapTableNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchMapViewController] autorelease];
[searchMapViewController release];

atestViewController = [[AboutTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *AboutNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:atestViewController] autorelease];
[atestViewController release];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchTableNavController, mapTableNavController,  AboutNavController, nil];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is why I wasn't able to do it.. 
I never coded a tabbar , does rewrite the tabbar in code instead of IB will enable me to do all the connections to the tableviews in the IB or I need to make them also in code?

Comment: you make all of those in IB - your tabbars load up viewControllers (in my example above searchMapViewController & atestViewController etc). You create VC's in IB as per usual. Let me stress that you probably can do it in all in IB - I've just always found this layer much easier to code than to do in IB.